# collect and create tab separated matrix

Tags: shell, scripting, comm

I have 6 text files (each corresponds to a specific sample) and each file looks like this:

```
Gene_ID Gene_Name   Strand  Start   End Length  Coverage    FPKM    TPM
ENSMUSG00000102735  Gm7369  +   4610471 4611406 936 0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000025900  Rp1 -   4290846 4409241 10926   0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000104123  Gm37483 -   4363346 4364829 1484    0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000102175  Gm6119  -   4692219 4693424 1206    0.328358    0.015815    0.008621
```

I want to collect all the elements from 1 & 2 column in one file and corresponding tpm values(9th column) for each sample in a new file, so wherever there is no tpm value enter 0.

My output file should look like this:

```
gene_id gene_name sample1_tpm sample2_tpm sample3_tpm ......sample6_tpm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `awk` to gather TPM values from all 6 input files `file1`…`file6` in an array indexed by gene_id and gene_name, and finally prints the consolidated TPM values for each array index. Missing TPM values are replaced by 0.

`awk '
   BEGIN { 
       f=0
   } 
   {
       if ($1 == "Gene_ID") {
          f++; getline;
       }
       i = $1 " " $2
       row[i] = row[i] " " (($9 == "") ? "0" : $9)
   }
   END {
      for (i in row) print i,row[i]
   }
' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl script that does what you want.  It builds up a hashed array (indexed by a string made up of "gene_id gene_name") containing an array of tpm samples.

Once it's finished reading all the files, it prints out each element of the hashed array.  Note the script does not require exactly 6 elements, nor is it limited to <= 6 - it will work for any number of tpm elements.

If some gene_id's have 6 tpm array elements while others have 1 or 5 or 1000 elements, each gene_id will be printed with the exact number of tmp elements detected for that gene_id/gene_name.  See below for extra code you can add to treat this as an error rather than a feature.

Input can be provided on stdin and/or by giving it filenames to process on the command line.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

my %samples = () ;

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
    next if (m/^Gene_ID|^$/);

    my ($gene_id, $gene_name, undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef, $tpm) = split;
    $tpm = 0 unless (defined($tpm));

    push @{ $samples{"$gene_id $gene_name"} }, $tpm;
}

foreach my $key ( keys %samples ) {
    my ($gene_id, $gene_name) = split(/\s+/,$key);

    print "$gene_id\t$gene_name\t", join("\t", @{ $samples{"$gene_id $gene_name"} }), "\n";
}
```

The script's output is tab-delimited.  If you prefer something else, edit the `print` line in the script and replace ALL the `\t`'s with your preferred delimiter.

If you want to produce an error message and exit if there are not exactly 6 tpm elements printed for each gene_id, add the following code immediately after the `my ($gene_id, $gene_name) = split(/\s+/,$key)` line:

```
    my $count = scalar @{ $samples{"$gene_id $gene_name"} };
    if ($count != 6) { die "Warning: $gene_id $gene_name has $count element(s)\n"};
```

---

Sample Output:

I made 6 copies of the sample data you provided, called `sample.txt` to `sample6.txt`.  Saved the `perl` script above as `sample.pl`, made it executable with `chmod +x sample.pl`, and ran it:

```
$ ./sample.pl sample*.txt
ENSMUSG00000104123  Gm37483 0   0   0   0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000102175  Gm6119  0.008621    0.008621    0.008621    0.008621    0.008621    0.008621
ENSMUSG00000102735  Gm7369  0   0   0   0   0   0
ENSMUSG00000025900  Rp1 0   0   0   0   0   0
```